# Import .jar into KMM Project Shared Layer

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a Kotlin-Multiplatform project and I have a certain dependency in shared/build.gradle.kts for `iosMain` for which I want to edit the source code.

###### shared/build.gradle.kts

```
kotlin {
  sourceSets {
    val androidMain by getting { ... }
    val iosMain by getting {
      dependencies { 
        implementation("app.cash.sqldelight:native-driver:2.0.0")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To my understanding, in order to do that, I have to get the .jar file for the library, edit the code, and then add that jar to Android Studio.

## What I Tried

**Adding jar dependency into iosMain normally**

1. I tried downloading the `native-driver-2.0.0.jar` jar from the [maven repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/app/cash/sqldelight/native-driver/2.0.0/), and then putting it in shared/libs directory in my project.
2. Next, I replaced `implementation("app.cash.sqldelight:native-driver:2.0.0")` with `implementation(files("libs/native-driver-2.0.0.jar"))`.

However, this doesn't work. The ios app doesn't build anymore due to 'unresolved references', and I have no idea why.

**Adding jar dependency into iosMain via top-level declaration**

I also noticed that when I had originally added the .jar file to Android Studio, right clicked it, and selected the "Add as Library" option, a dialog popped up saying, "Studio cannot determine what kind of files the chosen items contain. Choose the appropriate categories from the list". \

It didn't seem to matter which option I selected from the list (Classes, External Annotations, Jar Directory, JavaDocs, Native Library Location, Source Archive Directory, Sources). The ones I tried would all just add a top level block into my shared/build.gradle.kts:

```
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        val iosMain by getting { ... }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("libs/native-driver-2.0.0.jar")
}
```

After Android Studio synced, a dropdown arrow appeared under the jar file in the Project-View. This did not happen when I added the jar dependency in iosMain as mentioned previously.

I was wondering if it had to do with the dependency being in a top-level block, so I also tried:

```
dependencies {
    "iosMainImplementation"(files("native-driver-2.0.0.jar"))
}
```

This syntax should be equivalent to placing the dependency in the `iosMain` dependency block according to [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#set-dependencies-at-top-level), but my project did not build after this, nor did Android Studio add the dropdown arrow for the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit shared jars like that, really. Generally speaking, the source from a maven repo is there for debugging and browsing, not editing. That's for standard Java dependencies. For KMP, on the iOS side, the Kotlin compiler outputs a completely different format for native libraries.

If you want to edit the driver, you should fork SQLDelight, and publish your own locally, or just implement `SqlDriver` in your code and use that instead of the provided driver.

https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight

The native driver is here: https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/master/drivers/native-driver/src/nativeMain/kotlin/app/cash/sqldelight/driver/native/NativeSqlDatabase.kt#L100

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.

Yes, I considered just copying over the code, but I may end up having to add several different files and dependencies.

As for forking the repo, I did consider that since github repos can be used as gradle dependencies, but I'm not sure if it's possible to only add a dependency for the native-driver in the giant repo. Are you suggesting that I publish to a place like maven?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I see you mentioned publishing "locally". I haven't heard of that before. I'll look into it.